# how to host github pages with google domain

Tags: hosting, github-pages, google-domain-api

I have a github page up and running, and I wanted located at a custom url, so I purchased domain names from google domains and put the domain name in a CMAKE file.  It's not working, so I think I'm missing something about how to host sites and how this process works.  I don't mind researching the answer, but I'm totally lost at this point.  Could someone help me out or point me in the right direction? Thanks

for more info i bought "name-name.com" and put "name-name.com" in the CMAKE file. is this even the right address? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[`CNAME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record), not [`CMAKE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake). Very different things.

Follow [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/): it worked pretty well for me.